# C++ volatile and operator overloading for CUDA application

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cuda, volatile

I have a class A that I overload its operator=. However it is required that I need to do something like this:

```
volatile A x;
A y;
x = y;
```

which raised an error while compiling

```
error: no operator "=" matches these operands
       operand types are: volatile A = A
```

If I removed volatile, it's compilable. Is there anyway to have this compiled without removing the "volatile" (and still keep the behavior of volatile) ?

---

Basically this is a CUDA program in which 'x' is a shared memory ( all threads can access and modify its value ). I want it to be "volatile" in order to avoid the compiler optimization and re-use the value instead of accessing the memory address.

More on the problem: at the beginning A is just a primitive type e.g integer, volatile worked as expected and doesn't cause any problem, now I want it to be a custom class ( integer 128-bit for example ). I'm not sure why C++ complain in this case but not with primitive data type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the `volatile` qualification is necessary, you'll have to add a volatile assignment operator to A (`A& A::operator=(const A&) volatile`).

`const_cast<A&>(x) = y` will make it compile, but will technically cause undefined behaviour, and will certainly remove the guarantees that `volatile` gives.

Comment: Thanks ! It is compiled. but too bad :(, it gives me the same behavior of no-volatile

Comment: @iKid: what behaviour were you expecting from `volatile`?

Comment: I added explanation to my question

Comment: Adding to this, think carefully about how you actually implement this function - `volatile` means the destination can be written by someone else while you are writing it too, so make sure you set up your memory fences or whatever

Answer (score 4):

The "volatile isn't a lot of use in C++ threading" comment is irrelevant to the question, which is CUDA-specific.  volatile is needed for warp synchronous coding in CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

volatile isn't a lot of use in C++ threading (see Dave Butenhof's explanation at http://www.lambdacs.com/cpt/FAQ.html#Q56).  It's not sufficient to ensure your program flushes the data written out of core-local cache to a point where other programs can see the updates in shared memory, and given almost everyone's multi-core these days, that's a serious problem.  I suggest you use proper threading synchronisation methods, such as boost's if your portability needs match it, or perhaps POSIX mutexes and condition variables, failing that more architecture dependent techniques like memory barriers or atomic operations that implicitly sync memory between cores.

I'm sure you want it to be fast, but fast and unstable isn't generally as useful as slow and reliable, especially if you ship a product that's only unstable on your customer's hardware.

Comment: Especially considering that `pthread_mutex`es can be incredibly lightweight

Comment: Because everybody runs on POSIX, amirite?

Comment: @DeadMG: no, which is why we have portable wrappers like Boost.Thread, and the C++0x thread support library.

Comment: Exactly. Recommending POSIX directly is just not the right thing to do compared to boost::thread.

Comment: Thanks, feeling like C++ was poorly designed in this case

Comment: "volatile isn't a lot of use in C++."  This is as much nonsense as saying "const isn't a lot of use in C++."  The problem with `volatile` isn't `volatile` but the programmers who think `volatile` is some magical thread synchronization primitive that's broken.  It's not.

Comment: @DeadMG/Mike: fair call - answer updated.  @John: check out the link I inserted - it's not required for inter-thread synchronisation and may harm performance.  May still be useful for async signal handling or low-level device control etc., but that's irrelevant to the question... have updated my wording in the answer to reflect that.

Comment: thanks guys, the most frustrated thing here is that it does work in case of primitive data type but in object class. If there is no way to re-use the old one (which I want to keep the speedy) I have to code a very similar method just for the sake of "non-volatile" adaptiveness.

Comment: @iKid: don't let yourself think primitive types "work". Simply being able to compile is no guarantee of reliable results on a multi-CPU/core computer. Even if your testing on such a machine looks fine, it can still break when your program is unlucky enough to be preempted and put onto another CPU... most likely when the host's heavily loaded. You simply must use proper synchronisation mechanisms if you want a reliable program... that's what they're designed for. If you really measure performance with a mutex and it's a problem, you might try an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a copy constructor

```
volatile A& operator=(volatile A&) volatile;
```

worked for me with nvcc. Note that you may have to pass around the non-primitive type by reference only. Else you'll need more copy-constructors that convert volatile instances to non-volatile whenever the non-primitive type is passed by value to a non-volatile parameter.
It really boils down to establishing volatile-correctness (much like const-correctness).